# Error al usar "open": LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Google Chrome.app with error -610.non-zero return code

Tags: cmd, shell, ansible

Estoy intentando abrir una nueva ventana de chrome con un path específico desde ansible. El comando que uso es el siguiente:

```
ansible -a 'open --new -a "google chrome" --args "x.com"' host
```

Lo he probado en local y funciona, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo desde Ansible, me da el siguiente error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Google Chrome.app with error -610.non-zero return code
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa eso? ¿Existe alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Me late que hay problemas de permisos:

```
$ chmod +x {Ruta de tu archivo ansible}
```

Intenta también utilizar `http://dominio.com` o `https://dominio.com`

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, el problema no es los permisos ni el host, creo que va un poco el tema por un usuario conectado que tenga interfaz gráfica para poder ejecutar la app, pero no logro solucionarlo aún.

Comment: Esa información NO ha sido especificada en la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Si lo pregunto es porque previamente lo he buscado por Internet y no lo he conseguido, no he cogido la primera publicación que hay y la he copiado, como tu respuesta :).

Comment: Nuevamente, esa información TAMPOCO ha sido especificada en la pregunta, si eso has intentado, inclúyelo en tu pregunta. Entre más detalles, mejor tanto para ti como para quienes desean colaborar contigo en la solución. De haber sabido que has buscado e intentado lo que dice "la primera publicación que hay", no te hubiera dado parte de mi tiempo, aquí unas últimas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 . Saludos :)